# SFSafariViewController: open file protected with OAuth

Tags: ios, oauth, http-headers, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I need to display a `PDF` file stored on the server and protected with the OAuth scheme (i.e. the client should sent the token with each request).

I'd also would like to have the share button available, which comes by default with `SFSafariViewController`. Is there any way to add a custom authorization header to the `SFSafariViewController`'s request? Or the only way to achieve the aforementioned behavior is to create a custom `UIViewController` with `WKWebView` as it's `view`?